# How to select a parameter from json-like structure in Postgresql?

Tags: json, postgresql

My database has a column that contains json-like data structure (but no actual json markup) It looks like this:

```
---
ID: "-2293428132623007080"
RES_ID: '0'
NUMBER: "ДЕП002М Москва-Черновцы"
TRIP_SEATS_MAP: 'true'
SHOW_PICKUP_DROPOFF: 'false'
HAS_TRANSFER: 'false'
PLACES_COUNT: '49'...
```

I need to select HAS_TRANSFER value from it. Parameters are separated as rows, there is no delimiter. Is there a way to select a separate parameter value?

Comment: What is column  data type?

Comment: "trip_yaml" text COLLATE "default"

Answer (score 0):

One way is just extracting data between `HAS_TRANSFER:` and line break `\r`

```
with t(col) as(
    select 'ID: "-2293428132623007080"
    RES_ID: ''0''
    NUMBER: "ДЕП002М Москва-Черновцы"
    TRIP_SEATS_MAP: ''true''
    SHOW_PICKUP_DROPOFF: ''false''
    HAS_TRANSFER:     ''false''
    PLACES_COUNT: ''49'''::text
    union all
    select 'ID: "-2293428132623007080"
    RES_ID: ''0''
    NUMBER: "ДЕП002М Москва-Черновцы"
    TRIP_SEATS_MAP: ''true''
    SHOW_PICKUP_DROPOFF: ''false''
    HAS_TRANSFER:''bla''
    PLACES_COUNT: ''49'''::text
)

-- below is actual query:
select  substring(col from  'HAS_TRANSFER:\s*([^\r]+)')  from t
```

Comment: Thank you! It didn't work fully as expected. Your example works, but when I ran it on my data I got everything starting from 'false' and to the end, disregarding the line ends.

However, you pointed me in a right direction and I eventually came up with the following:

SUBSTRING (
 trip_yaml
 FROM
  (
   POSITION ('HAS_TRANSFER' IN trip_yaml) + 14
  ) FOR 7
)

This is not elegant, but it worked